# Why this formula not working?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to import data from web page to Google spreadsheet by function IMPORTHTML, IMPORTDATA .

The formulas that i used are
`IMPORTDATA("https://www.screener.in/screens/1/The-Bull-Cartel/")` 
which resulted in some java type output and

other is 
`IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/1/The-Bull-Cartel/","table",1)` 
which give error "imported content is empty".

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTDATA returns the content of the URL. When the URL points to a web page it returns the source code.

IMPORTHTML looks at the source code of web page referred by the URL. It returns "imported content is empty" because the source code doesn't include a table defined by HTML tags (`<table>`) because the displayed table is built by JavaScript code not by HTML tags.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So what do you suggest to get the data the data from that link.

Comment: @user9378515 Please checkout the tag wiki of [tag:web-scraping]